# Best practice when implementing a service client that wraps Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, pagination, guzzle

I have to build a PHP class, basically, a client that wraps Guzzles php client to get and send data to a REST API. This client will be sitting in a composer package that will be required by a Laravel app

What would be the best way to implement this in a way that I can test the package/client.

Currently, my implementation is to have a method in the class 'call()'
this will wrap Guzzles ->request

similar to

```
    public function call(string $method , string $path, array $query = [], array $auth = [])
    {
        $query   = array_merge($query, ['api_key' => $this->apikey]);
        $uriPath = $this->buildApiUri($path);

        try {
            $resp = $this->client->request($method, $uriPath, [
                'auth'  => $auth,
                'query' => $query,
            ]);

        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            Log::error('FAIL ' . $uriPath . ' fetch: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->jsonDecodeOrError($uriPath, $resp);
    } 

  protected function buildApiUri($path)
    {
        return '/api/' . $this->api_version . $path;
    }
```

I'm also thinking the only way to test this would be to pass the guzzle client into my own client, so I can leverage Guzzles mock handlers

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function __construct($apikey, Client $client, $max_retries = 5)
```

My client will have only a handful of methods to start with which essentially calls various rest endpoints.

The other problem I'm facing is pagination. The rest API I'm talking to returns paged data, and I would like to handle pagination within my client.

ie - If a call to **/users** returns **10 users per page, with a total of 100 users**, I would like the **->getUsers()** method in my client class to return 100 records.

Can do leverage guzzle or do I loop over each request until I get all the records back from the API.

The package does not need to be Laravel specific (service provider)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `The rest API I'm talking to returns paged data, and I would like to handle pagination within my client` if the rest calls allow for paging it's no different then paging anything really, you just forward the current page you want, the number of rows or whatever the API allows you too.  The first question is either too broad or opinion related.  But I never directly call an API in my code without wrapping that API first, that way if I need to change the API I only have to look in one place for the code that ties my stuff to their stuff.

Comment: Instead of `call(string $method` I would write individual methods and then do a call, otherwise you are still dependent on their API, because $method is being passed into your wrapper and is specific to the API, for example say there is a method `update` well if you code `$wrapper->call('update'` maybe a similar API uses `edit`  So now in your non-wrapper code you have to change `update` to `edit` where if you do a `update()` method that makes that call, you only need to change it in the wrapper.  If that makes sense, you can still use a generic call method, but I would do it protected

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix with regards to pagination i was looking at this https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/iterators/resource-iterators.html
I've never used it so was unsure.

with the generic call() method are you suggesting that I put my guzzel->request() method in each of my getUser(), getProperties(), etc instead of  getUsers() { $this->call('get',,,,) }